# Can Sex be counted as a form of cardio?

Tags: cardio, sex

So I am on this 12 week transformation by Kris Gethin, and I am supposed to do 20mins of cardio twice a day, every day. So I'm thinking of alternatives of climbing stairs, running ,etc.

**So I thought - could sex be a form of cardio?**

Having sex for 20mins twice a day would be waaaay more pleasant and not as monotonous as running :)

Comment: I'd need some data to draw any conclusions, care to wear a heart rate monitor next time? :P

Comment: Here is an article that shows you how to "exercise" in the bed room  http://www.fitnessmagazine.com/health/sex/better-sex-guide/sex-positions-that-double-as-exercise/?page=1

Comment: Depends on how active you are, for example: http://xkcd.com/414/

Comment: @Moses http://xkcd.com/940/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When my wife was on bed rest when she was pregnant with our daughter I asked if it precluded sex.  The rhetorical question I got back was:

> Does it get her heart rate up?

The answer is, yes it is a form of cardio workout.  The question then becomes a matter of the quality of cardio.  In other words, how high does your heart rate go?  You want to be in the aerobic zone to do what your plan wants for you.  You don't want the heart rate too high, nor do you want it too low.

Of course the other side of the problem is a willing partner for 2x/day.  You or your partner may become sore and need a break--particularly if you are doing what is necessary to keep your heart rate up.  Using a heart rate monitor will help you know how your cardio work is doing, but it lessens the enjoyment of sex when you are concentrating on something else (like your heart rate).

Besides, do you really want something that is meant to be fun to now be viewed as work?  I'm of the mindset to keep work and play separate.  While merging them makes work more fun, it makes play less enjoyable.  Keeping them separate activities works better for me.

Comment: I don't agree with keeping work and play separate. If you can find a fun way to work out, by all means, do so.

Comment: While we have differing opinions on work/play separation, I'm sure we can agree that we need both.  :)